# res.redirect not workig when working with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using react as frontend and made api using express I have the following code I have stored jwt token in the cookies while logging in for the first then when trying to login in again I check if there is already a token in the cookies if there is token in the cookie (currently I am not verifying it I just want it to work) redirect the user to profile page but it doesn't work.
Although an XMLHttpRequest can be seen in the network tab ([click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjm1A.jpg)) but it doesn't work.
PS - I am using Axios in the frontend to make a get request.

```
loginRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cookieFound = req.cookies["login-token"];
    if (cookieFound) {
      res.redirect("profile");
    } else {
      res.redirect("login");
    }
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json("Ooops something went wrong!");
  }
});
```

code to make a get request in the frontend

```
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("/login");
  }, []);
```

EDIT :-

Backend

```
 loginRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cookieFound = req.cookies["login-token"];
    if (cookieFound) {
      res.send("/profile");
    }
    // res.status(200).json(cookieFound);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json("Ooops something went wrong!");
  }
});
```

Client

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const alreadyLoggedIn = async () => {
      const url = await Axios.get("/login");

      window.location = url.data;
    };
    alreadyLoggedIn();
  }, []);
```

Comment: You can not redirect the frontend, via the response to a _background_ request. You need to make your server-side code return the new URL as _data_, and then perform the "redirect" on the client side using JS.

Comment: @CBroe what do you mean by new URL ? I am trying to check if user already have the token if he has then redirect it to profile page.
I tried doing res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/profile") it doesnt' work either.

Comment: _"what do you mean by new URL ?"_ - well the one you want to redirect to, either `profile` or `login`. _"I tried doing res.redirect("localhost:3000/profile") it doesnt' work either."_ - of course it doesn't, because that still has the exact same issue - you are responding to a _background_ request here.

Comment: What is new URL ?

Comment: Did I not just say that?!? I mean the one you want to redirect to.

Comment: @CBroe It worked ! I have edited my post although its working but could you review my code specially the backend one because I think there is something missing like I have written the code for if the token founds but not for it the token doesn't found.

Answer (score 0):

To what you have entered I think you should change `window.location = url.data` to `window.location = window.location.hostname + url.data;`
In your current setup the total url will be set to `/profile` while you want `yourwebsite.com/profile`